# Correcting a ldap_search(): Search: Operations error

Tags: php, post, ldap, operation

I am using php along with ldap to query information based on a users input.

Referencing the [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-search.php) I use the ldap_search control to pass on the connection bindings and the tree (OU) that the clients belong to. I also pass along a filter variable which should take the user input and make this a parameter for the search like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adsi/search-filter-syntax?redirectedfrom=MSDN).

When running my program I receive the error: `Warning: ldap_search(): Search: Operations error` followed by the line number.
I know that the error is coming from my use of `$filter` on the line that I try to use ldap_search so I know it is not the other arguments.

```
$ldaphost= 'domain.com';
$ldapuser= 'username';
$ldappass= 'password';
$ldaptree="OU=Test";
$ldapconn= ldap_connect($ldaphost) or die("Could not connect to LDAP server.");

$search= $_POST['text'];

if($ldapconn) {
   $ldapbind = ldap_bind($ldapconn, $ldapuser, $ldappass) or die ("Error trying to bind: ".ldap_error($ldapconn));

    if ($ldapbind) {

        $filter="&((CN=*.$search.*)(objectClass=computer))";
        $result = ldap_search($ldapconn,$ldaptree,$filter) or die ("Error in search query: ".ldap_error($ldapconn));       
 //other methods }
```

Any ideas about what I am doing wrong with filter? I have also tried explicit queries that do not rely on user input such as `CN=Computer1` and receive the same error.

I have looked at other solutions for this error that suggested adding
`ldap_set_option($ldap, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);  ldap_set_option($ldap, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);`
as a fix and more but have not found one that works for me.
I have also tried multiple deviations of the query for $filter but only get bad filter errors.

Any code examples for further resources to help me solve this would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: The first thing is that there are 2 conditions you want to apply: `(CN=*.$search.*)` and `(objectClass=computer)`, but there is no operator. It's likely you need both conditions to be met, so for exmaple in this case the filter should be : `"(&(CN=*.$search.*)(objectClass=computer))"`.

Comment: Eric, thanks for responding to this. I have tried it with both one condition without an operator and with two conditions and the operator like you listed. I must have missed that when initially posting. When using your code sample I get the same error. Any other ideas?

Comment: Yes, I didn't see it in the first place but `OU=Test` is not a valid base dn, it should point to the full dn of `ou=Test`, including domain components, eg. `OU=Test,dc=domain,dc=com`.

Comment: Looks like this got me some progress to where I have a 'no such object' error until I removed the OU completely and set $ldaptree to be just the DC values of the DN, omitting the OU completely. I now have an undefined index error for another line but it looks like that is an issue with new versions of php so I think this issue is resolved. Again, thank you very much!